# ngModel llamando a una función desde la vista

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

¿Puedo en angular4 hacer algo parecido a esto en un template?:

```
    <input  (input)="number= $event.target.value; ChangeValues()"  id="number" type="number">
```

si es posible hacerlo, ¿dónde debería estar declarada la funcion `ChangeValues()` en mi component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto tu respuesta y realmente no se hace de esa manera (aunque funcione).

Te dejaré un ejemplo simple: [`Ver ejemplo online`](https://embed.plnkr.co/XPqwDe6A1BHU4ePbbpCz/)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input (input)="changeValues($event);"  
                    name="number" 
                    type="number">
                    <p>{{prueba_salida}}</p>`,
})
export class App {

  prueba_salida:string = '';

  constructor() {
  }

  changeValues(event) {
    this.prueba_salida = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Lo que hacemos en el evento `(input)`, es asignar el método `changeValues($event)` y pasamos el objeto del evento como parámetro.

Después en el componente puedes manipular los valores, según necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

No se si es la mejor manera.Pero lo he conseguido añadiendo una función a un objeto del componente.

```
<input  (input)="calculator.number= $event.target.value; calculator.ChangeValues();"  name="number" type="number">
```